# Deserialize variably named elements and get the name of these elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML provided by a vendor so I can't modify how this XML file is generated. I want to deserialize this file into objects but sometimes it happens that the important information I want to get is the name of the element itself. For example:

```
   <type>
          <BOOL />
   </type>
```

I don't have this problem when the type is not a primitive because I would get something like this:

```
   <type>
          <derived name="CustomDatatype" />
   </type>
```

The element will be always named as "derived" and have an attribute "name" so I just check if the derived element exists and get the value of name.

Back to the problem, inside the "type" element I have another element named as "BOOL" but it could be any value type within a fixed list of 19 primitive datatypes so I ended up doing this:

```
public class XmlType
{
  //Here I show just two datatypes but remember that the list is larger
  [XmlElement("BOOL",IsNullable = true)]
  public string boolType{ get; set;}
  [XmlElement("BYTE",IsNullable = true)]
  public string byteType{ get; set;}
  .
  .
  .
  [XmlElement("derived",IsNullable = true)]
  public DerivedTypeXml derivedType{ get; set;}

  [XmlIgnore]
  public string Type
  {
    get
    {
      if (this.boolType != null) 
      {
        return "BOOL";
      } else if (this.byteType != null) {
        return "BYTE";
      }else if(this.derivedType!=null)
      {
        return this.derivedType.Name;
      }else
      {
        return "unknown";
      }
    }
  }

  }
}
```

As you can see I have to declare the possible elements allowing them to be null and then check if they exist or not one by one and tell what they have to return. This feels like too much work and hacky so I wanted to know if there is a generic solution for this.

EDIT: Ok, the answer from alexander is right but I had to tweak it a bit in order to fit my needs.

```
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string primitiveType=string.Empty;

        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                if(primitiveType!=string.Empty)
                {
                    return this.primitiveType;
                }
                else if(this.derivedType!=null)
                {
                    return this.derivedType.Name;

                }else{
                    return "#UNKNOWN";
                }

            }
        }


    private void XmlSerializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (TypeXml)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
        obj.primitiveType = e.Element.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class XmlType
{
    [XmlElement("derived", IsNullable = true)]
    public DerivedTypeXml derivedType { get; set; }

    // No need [XmlIgnore]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Create an `UnknownElement` event handler on an instance of the `XmlSerializer`.

```
xmlSerializer.UnknownElement += XmlSerializer_UnknownElement;

private void XmlSerializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (XmlType)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    obj.Type = e.Element.Name;
}
```

That's all!

When the serializer will meet unknown tags, such as BOOL, BYTE, etc. will be called the event handler. Thus `Type` property is assigned the name of this tag.

Be sure to remove the `XmlIgnore` attribute so that the event handler was called for this property.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, that is what I was looking for. I had to tweak your code a bit tho, just check it out my edit if you are curious.